# Print view in twig template

Tags: views, 8, theming

My page--front.html.twig is working ok. I want to print the block_1 display of the recent_comments view. I tried this but it does not seem to work.

```
{{ view.comments_recent(block_1) }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can preprocess a new variable and use `views_embed_view` like:

```
$variables['my_view'] = views_embed_view('view_id', 'display_id');
```

So in your case:

```
$variables['my_view'] = views_embed_view('comments_recent', 'block_1');
```

And then in the twig file:

```
{{ my_view }}
```

See [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.module/function/views_embed_view/). It can also take arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You want the Twig Tweak module. It provides a function to render a view directly in a twig template without the need for preprocessing.

https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak

It also provides a few other functions which might come in handy.